# Update used pimple version in Silex application

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex, pimple

I'm currently creating an application using [silex 1.3](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/download).

I want to use the [dflydev doctrine orm service provider](https://packagist.org/packages/dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider).

For this service provider pimple >=2.1 is needed - but my silex version comes with pimple 1.x.

I've tried to install a newer version via composer, but this results in an error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - silex/silex v1.3.0 requires pimple/pimple ~1.0 -> no matching package foun d.
>       - silex/silex v1.3.0 requires pimple/pimple ~1.0 -> no matching package foun d.
>       - silex/silex v1.3.0 requires pimple/pimple ~1.0 -> no matching package foun d.
>       - Installation request for silex/silex v1.3.0 -> satisfiable by silex/silex[ v1.3.0].

So my question is: how Can I update this pimple version?

**EDIT: I've just seen that there's an older release of the dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider, which uses pimple 1.x, so I guess I have to use this version.**
Nevertheless, I would be intereseted if an update is (theoretical) possible.

Comment: you could be bold and try with Silex2 resp. dev-master, there is "pimple/pimple": "~3.0", not sure how stable this it atm though

Answer (score 0):

Considering how closely Silex is coupled to Pimple, it is not possible to upgrade Pimple without breaking a lot of things in Silex. That said, the upgrade has been a work in progress for a while.

There are several closed issues to update Silex to the new version. [Here's one](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/1281), though there does not seem to be any roadmap for the upgrade.

The `master` branch of Silex has [upgraded](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/composer.json) to Pimple 3.0. I would watch that branch for any progress. However, as I'm sure you noticed, Pimple 2-3 is not backwards compatible with Pimple 1.0, so if you do upgrade at some point, your other 3rd party service providers will not work until they are updated as well.